# Ignore Server Certificate Errors For Single WCF Call, not for entire application

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

All,

I want to make a WCF call to a WCF Service over SSL but I want to ignore the SSL Cert validation.

I know I can do this:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
            ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);
```

and that will trust all certs application wide.  My issue is that I want to just trust all certs for one specific call.  I want all other calls to validate server certs.

What kind of Binding do I need to pass to

```
new ChannelFactory<MyService>(binding, endpointAddress);
```

inorder to achieve this?